# var_dump returns bool(false)

Tags: php, mysql, var-dump

I am absolute beginner with php and mysql .. i want to put (year, month, demand) in the (table) in database but `var_dump` shows Bool(false) and nothing is being passed to the database ... it is also shows successfully registered alert.
here is my full code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simulation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Registration Page</h2>
        <a href="home.php"> Click here to go back </a><br/><br/>
        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
           Enter year: <input type="number" name="year" required="required" /> <br/>
           Enter month: <input type="number" name="month" required="required" /> <br/>
           Enter demand: <input type="number" name="demand" required="required" /> <br/>
           <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $year = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['year']);
        $month = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['month']);
        $demand = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['demand']);

        echo " year is" .$year. "<br/>";
        echo " month is" .$month. "<br/>";
        echo " demand is" .$demand;

        mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
        mysql_select_db("first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database

        $qu = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (year, month, demand) VALUES ('$year','$month','$demand')"); //Inserts the value to table users
        var_dump ($qu);
        die();
        Print '<script>alert("Successfully Registered!");</script>'; // Prompts the user
        Print '<script>window.location.assign("register.php");</script>'; // redirects to register.php
    }

?>
```

Comment: don't add a space between var_dump and ($qu).

Comment: @SableFoste removed it and nothing new happened

Comment: is your table really named table? recuse its a reserved word: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html and thefore should be warped in back-ticks

Comment: @Dagon yes it is named table and the whole database name is first_db .. should i change table to any other name ?

Comment: add back ticks around \``table`\`

Comment: After send form do you see `year is x`,`month  is x`,`demand  is x`?

Comment: @Dagon tried it and nothing happened .. i will try to change the whole table name for another name to keep away from reserved words .. i hope this may solve the problem

Comment: @yonessafari yes i see
the out put is
year is234
month is22
demand is4345bool(false)

Comment: @Dagon changed the whole table with new one named users and the same is happening

Comment: add ` or die(mysql_error());` to the end of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table` is reserved word and you must change your table name and use below query:

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name (year, month, demand) VALUES ('$year','$month','$demand')
```

Comment: my table name is table as written in the query

Comment: @yonessafari update your answer to state that `table` is a reserved word which is most likely causing the issue.

Comment: @yonessafari changed the whole table with a new one named users and the same is happening

Answer (score 0):

problem solved with changing the whole table to a new one named users as table is a reserved word.
and writing a query like

```
$qu = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (year, month, demand) VALUES ('$year','$month','$demand')");
```

Comment: it is unlikely that back-ticks (you did net try regular quotes?) on table did not work if changing the table name did - but all fine.

Comment: above you use quotes not back-ticks ```````````=back ticks, '''''''''''''=single quote. key to the left of the number 1 on an 'American' keyboard

Comment: Go to the `phpmyadmin` and click the table `users` then click the tab `sql` and then click `insert` now copy this query here .... TNQ

Comment: @Dagon OH so sorry for that .. i am a beginner as mentioned
thank you for helping me and i will edit the answer to be useful for others

Answer (score -2):

If $qu returns false means that the query have some kind of error and can't execute

In this line

```
$qu = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (year, month, demand) VALUES ('$year','$month','$demand')");
```

you must append strings more like this:

```
$qu = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (year, month, demand) VALUES ('".$year."','".$month."','".$demand."')");
```

Comment: Wide open to SQL injection attack.  Don't use mysql.  Use prepared statements (PDO or mysqli).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new and there are some things I do not know yet.